# Python Turtle Graphics Filling a Non-Closed Polygon

Tags: python, fill, turtle-graphics

I thought (assumed) that the begin_fill()/end_fill() commands would only "fill" a shape if the shape was "closed". Consider the following:
    import turtle

```
turtle.color("red")
turtle.begin_fill()
turtle.forward(100)
turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(100)
turtle.end_fill()
```

Python completes the figure and fills it in - which is not what I want. How do I ensure that only a **closed** polygon will be filled in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess we could subclass Turtle and change the rules:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

class Yertle(Turtle):
    def end_fill(self):
        if len(self._fillpath) > 3 and self._fillpath[0] == self._fillpath[-1]:
            super().end_fill()  # warning, Python3 syntax!
        else:
            self.end_poly()
```

Now we can do:

```
turtle = Yertle()
screen = Screen()

turtle.color("red")

turtle.begin_fill()
turtle.forward(100)
turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(100)
turtle.end_fill()

turtle.penup()
turtle.home()
turtle.pendown()

turtle.color("green")

turtle.begin_fill()
turtle.backward(100)
turtle.right(90)
turtle.backward(100)
turtle.home()
turtle.end_fill()

screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]

Warning, this solution is ***fragile***!  It depends on knowledge of the underlying implementation which might change in a future release.  But if you absolutely gotta have it...

Comment: So you're telling me that I need to define a class to do what I would have thought to be the "normal" operation, i.e., only fill a shape if it is closed?

Comment: @Simon, your model may not be the norm for everyone -- some folks might expect `begin_fill()` and `end_fill()` to actually ***fill*** something.  I agree it's a documentation flaw that `end_poly()` mentions the automatic connection back to the first vertex and that `end_fill()` doesn't.  And perhaps it should be a optional flag to set.  However, you're using an OOP language and the class necessary to fix this is minimal and can go in the same file as your code.  And that's one of the points of OOP, the ability to override default behavior.

Comment: Thanks, I will adapt accordingly. I probably should have mentioned my profession in the beginning - I'm a teacher.  When I give an assignment to draw a shape and fill it, I want to be sure that the program works because the student has correctly calculated the distances & angles, not because of Python's generosity.